# How to write below/above the text in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tex

I want to have text above text (not superscript - `x^2`) but a `\overbrace` and text above it. (same for below the text)

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$\overbrace{\hbox{Text}}^{\hbox{text above}}$
$\underbrace{\hbox{Text}}_{\hbox{text below}}$
$\stackrel{\hbox{Text above}}{\hbox{Text below}}$
```

Comment: I need the underbrace to be under a matrix. how would you do that?

Comment: Similarly `$\underbrace{\matrix{1&2\cr 3&4}}_{\hbox{text below}}$`

Comment: How do you do it if you don't want the underbrace to be visible?